# Updating Folder Path - AutoHotKey

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I am trying to figure out how to update a path and I am unsure how to do it and I keep getting some errors.

I need to update the Sample Output that is Displayed on the EV Output. Any help would be great.

As you can see in the image Output sample is updating the selected Input folder. I need it to be the Info that is in EV Output.

Here is my Menu Code

```
;; MENU 
; Left Side Menu
Gui, Add, Button, x7 y7 w110 h30 gInput, Select Input Folder
Gui, Add, Checkbox, x7 y47 w730 h20 checked vCheck1,Include the last folder of the input folder in  the output?
Gui, Add, Text, x22 y82 w600 h20 , Output Sample:
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y82 w610 h20 vDisplayPath, %DisplayPath%  ;--Line needs to match EV Output
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y122 w110 h30 gOutputEV, Select EV Output
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y162 w110 h30 gOutputWC, Select WC Output
Gui, Add, Text, x127 y17 w275 h20 vDisplayInput, ;display selected folder - input
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y132 w250 h20 vDisplayEV, ;display selected folder -ev  <--- Selected to update Display Path
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y172 w250 h20 vDisplayWC, ;display selected folder - wc
Gui, Add, Text, x12 y215 w190 h20 , Last Name, First Name: ; Name Field
Gui, Add, Edit, x171 y215 w170 h30 vName, DoeJohn     ; Editable Name Type
Gui, Add, Text, x12 y250 w190 h30 , Collection Date (YYYYMMDD):
Gui, Add, Edit, x171 y250 w100 h30 r1 vtime,%TimeString%
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y280 w110 h30 gSubmit, Submit
; Right Side Menu
Gui, Add, Text, x757 y7 w130 h20 , Helpful Buttons:
Gui, Add, Button, x757 y77 w160 h30 gOpenTC, List Mounted TrueCrypt Devices
Gui, Add, Button, x757 y37 w160 h30 gMountTC, Auto-Mount TC Devices
Gui, Add, Button, x757 y217 w160 h30 gDismountTC, Dismount ALL TC Devices
; Version Info
Gui, Show, w936 h350, Mobile Robocopy Script v2.5,NoHide
GUI, Add, Picture, x550 y270 w350 h60, %MyPic%
Return
```

Here is my EV Code

```
OutputEV:
FileSelectFolder,OutputEV,, 3, Select EV Output Directory For Logs
if OutputEV =
   {
   MsgBox, You didn't select a log folder. Try again!
   return
   }
else
Guicontrol,1:,DisplayEV,%OutputEV%

    return
```

I have tried adding like Guicontrol,1:,DisplayOutPutEV,%DisplayOutPutEV% but I get errors. I just need Sample Output to match EV Output and I cant figure that out.

[image: Picture of problem]

Any help would be great.

Comment: @fischgeek I don't see reason for downvoting too. But at stackoverflow malignant downvoting is common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, it seems your issue is with this line

```
Guicontrol,1:,DisplayEV,%OutputEV%
```

You've built up your GUI with no identifier, buy you're trying to talk to a control on GUI 1 which doesn't exist. Remove the GUI identifier.

```
GuiControl,, DisplayEV, %OutputEV%
```

In your GUI, give your controls DIFFERENT variables

```
Gui, Add, Text, x22 y82 w600 h20 vlblOutputSample, Output Sample:
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y82 w610 h20 vDisplayPath, %DisplayPath%
```

Then, in your subroutine, just set both controls' text to the OutputEV variable.

```
GuiControl,, DisplayEV, %OutputEV%
GuiControl,, lblOutputSample, %OutputEV%
```

Comment: Whenever I go to add the vDisplayEV again it says 
Error: The same variable cannot be used more than one control.


So can I add under the new line that you fixed

         GuiControl,, DisplayOutPutEV, %DisplayOutPutEV% and add it where              vDisplayPath, %DisplayPath% was?

Comment: I removed all your g-labels except OutputEV, ran the code, selected a folder and it appeared in the text next to the button. So, it works. Your error is caused by something else. The duplicate error is from having the same variable declaration for more than one control. Double check your code.

Comment: I understand that. it does work. What I am saying is I want the Sample Output to be the Same as the EV Output. So have it displayed in 2 places.

So like in the sample pic I want Output Sample: to Display the same thing as EV Output.

Comment: I added to my answer.